# How do I upload file on an aspx page without using webforms?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload, pagemethods

I have an aspx page which already has a code for uploading file using "asp:FileUpload" and webform. On a different section of page, I want to add the functionality for a user to upload file. But i do not want to use webforms or "asp:fileupload".

So, I created an HTML file that i inject as an iframe inside a div tag on the aspx.

```
<div id="iUploadDoc" style="height:50px;">
<iframe name='FileUpload'   id='FileUpload' class='iUploadFrame' width='100%' frameborder='0' border='0'src='DocUpload.htm'></iframe></div>
```

I set the EnablePageMethods to true.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
```

And inside the HTML I made a form and with input type file.

```
<form method="POST" action="DocDetail.aspx.cs" id="docUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="fileUpload" class="inputLabel">Upload File</label>
            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files"/>

        </div>
    </form>
<div id="progUpload" style="display: none;">
            <p class="uploadBox">Uploading...</p>
        </div>
        <span id= "selectedFile" style="display: none;"></span><span id="fileName" style="display: none;"></span>
```

Now, I dont know what to put in the "action" param of form.
First on the iframe, below is the script i wrote:

```
window.onload = load;
function uploadDocFile() {  
    var prog = document.getElementById("progUpload");
    prog.style.cssText = 'display: block;';
    var x = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    var txt = "";
    var filePath = "";
    var fileName = "";
    if (x.value == "") {
        txt += "Select a file.";
        document.getElementById("selectedFile").innerHTML = txt;
    } else {
        filePath = x.value;
        fileName = filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        txt += "<br>Selected file: ";
        document.getElementById("selectedFile").innerHTML = txt;
        document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = fileName;
    }

    var formInfo = document.getElementById("docUpload");
    document.getElementById("docUpload").style.display = "none";
    window.parent.getFormData(formInfo, x ,x.value, fileName);
}

function load() {
    var e = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    //var formInfo = document.getElementById("docUpload");
    //fakeClick();
    e.onchange = function () {
        uploadDocFile();
    }
}
```

Then on the parent page, below is the script i wrote.

```
    DocUpload.prototype.uploadFileDoc= function (formInfo, uploadedFile, fileInfo, lastModifiedDate, name, extension, size, type) {
//blacklitsType is an array of types of file (similarly for blacklistExt) that should not be allowed to upload
if (indexOf.call(blackListType, type) < 0 && indexOf.call(blackListExt, extension) < 0) {    
var idParams = { OiD: ordId, pID: pId, QID: qId }
        var files = uploadedFile.files;
                    var fileEntries = [];
                    for (j = 0, len1 = files.length; j < len1; j++) {
                        file = files[j];
                        if (file.getAsEntry) {
                            entry = file.getAsEntry();
                        } else if (file.webkitGetAsEntry) {
                            entry = file.webkitGetAsEntry();
                        }
                        if (entry) {
                            isFyl = entry.isFile;
                            if (!isFyl) {
                                alert("You can not upload a folder. Uploading files (if present).");
                            } else {
                                fileItem = file.getAsFile();
                                fileEntries.push(fileItem);
                            }
                        } else if (!file.type && file.size % 4096 === 0) {
                            alert("You can not upload a folder. Uploading files (if present).");
                        } else {
                            fileEntries.push(file);
                        }
                    }


                PageMethods.UploadDocument(fileEntries[0], idParams, function (res) {
                    if (res == true) {
                        alert("File uploaded successfully.");                   
                    } else {                    
                        alert("File upload failed.");                   
                    }
                }, function (err) {
                    alert("ERROR: " + err._message);                
                });         

            } else {            
                window.alert('You cannot upload incorrect file types.');            
            }
            return;
        };

    DocUpload.prototype.getFormData = function (formInfo, uploadedFile, fileInfo, nameInfo) {
            var currDate, extension, lastModifiedDate, name, nameArr, size, type;
            currDate = new Date();
            lastModifiedDate = currDate;
            type = '';
            size = 512;
            name = nameInfo;
            nameArr = name.split(".");
            extension = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
            DocUpload.prototype.uploadFileDoc(formInfo, uploadedFile, fileInfo, lastModifiedDate, name, extension, size, type);
        };
    window.getFormData = DocUpload.prototype.getFormData;
```

The transfer of attributes of form from iframe to parent page work just fine. But how should i post it as file using PageMethod. Below is the page method in my code behind:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]           
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
    public static bool UploadDocument(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile,IdParams idParams) {
    bool err = false;
    try{ 
//code 
err= true;}
    catch(Exception ex){err = false;}
    return err;
        }
```

No matter how much tried, either I keep getting error regarding HTTPPostedFileBase or Serialization of child not allowed.Below are only some of the errors i keep getting (not at the same time):

```
No parameterless constructor System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase aspx, OR
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
```

What should i do?

Comment: Use `Request.Files`.

Comment: Please show your code, it could be various issues. Take a moment to read: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I have added quite a bit of my code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SLaks Can you please elaborate more? Also, i have added code if that helps